# How to rotate text in Pinta?

Tags: pinta

Is there any way to rotate text in Pinta?

I need to add some text for a y-axis label. I've been trying for a while to find a way myself, and I couldn't find anything relevant on the Internet either.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open a background image in Pinta.
2. Open Files file browser, go to the location of the image file that you opened in Pinta, select *Properties* and find the width and height of the image.
3. Select *File* -> *New* to open a new image the same width and height as the first image that you opened in Pinta. Click the transparent radio button to make this image transparent.
4. Click the Text tool (capital ) in the toolbox pane and type some text on the transparent image.
5. Select Layer Rotate/Zoom Layer… and rotate the transparent layer.

   [image]
6. Copy the transparent layer, click the background layer to select it, and paste the transparent layer over the background layer. Because the layer is transparent you will see only the text that you typed when you paste the transparent layer over the background layer.
7. Select the *Move Selected Pixels* tool (marked by a red arrow in the below screenshot) in the toolbox pane and move the transparent layer over the background layer to its desired position.

   [image]
8. Select *File* -> *Save As…* to save the edited background image.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is to put your text in without rotation, the using the selection tool select the area around the text and go to 'Image' and choose any of the rotate options provided there.